# Zipped Python generators with 2nd one being shorter: how to retrieve element that is silently consumed

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, generator, python-itertools

I want to parse 2 generators of (potentially) different length with `zip`:

```py
for el1, el2 in zip(gen1, gen2):
    print(el1, el2)
```

However, if `gen2` has less elements, one extra element of `gen1` is "consumed".

For example,

```py
def my_gen(n:int):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i

gen1 = my_gen(10)
gen2 = my_gen(8)

list(zip(gen1, gen2))  # Last tuple is (7, 7)
print(next(gen1))  # printed value is "9" => 8 is missing

gen1 = my_gen(8)
gen2 = my_gen(10)

list(zip(gen1, gen2))  # Last tuple is (7, 7)
print(next(gen2))  # printed value is "8" => OK
```

Apparently, a value is missing (`8` in my previous example) because `gen1` is read (thus generating the value `8`) before it realizes `gen2` has no more elements. But this value disappears in the universe. When `gen2` is "longer", there is no such "problem".

**QUESTION**: Is there a way to retrieve this missing value (i.e. `8` in my previous example)? ... ideally with a variable number of arguments (like `zip` does).

***NOTE***: *I have currently implemented in another way by using `itertools.zip_longest` but I really wonder how to get this missing value using `zip` or equivalent.*

***NOTE 2***: *I have created some tests of the different implementations in this REPL in case you want to submit and try a new implementation :) https://repl.it/@jfthuong/MadPhysicistChester*

Comment: The docs do note that "zip() should only be used with unequal length inputs when you don’t care about trailing, unmatched values from the longer iterables. If those values are important, use itertools.zip_longest() instead.".

Comment: @Ch3steR. But the question has nothing to do with "why". It literally reads "Is there a way to retrieve this missing value ...?" It seems that all the answers but mine conveniently forgot to read that part.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Strange indeed. I rephrased the question to be clearer on that aspect.

Comment: The basic problem is that there's no way to peek or push back into a generator. So once `zip()` has read `8` from `gen1`, it's gone.

Comment: @Barmar definitely, we all agreed on that. The question was more how to store it somewhere to be able to use it.

Comment: You should really consider selecting Raymond Hettinger's answer. It only uses the standard library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reuse code, the easiest solution is:

```
from more_itertools import peekable

a = peekable(a)
b = peekable(b)

while True:
    try:
        a.peek()
        b.peek()
    except StopIteration:
        break
    x = next(a)
    y = next(b)
    print(x, y)


print(list(a), list(b))  # Misses nothing.
```

You can test this code out using your setup:

```
def my_gen(n: int):
    yield from range(n)

a = my_gen(10)
b = my_gen(8)
```

It will print:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
[8, 9] []
```

Answer (score 40):

Right out of the box, [*zip()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is hardwired to dispose of the unmatched item. So, you need a way to remember values *before* they get consumed.

The itertool called [*tee()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) was designed for this purpose.  You can use it to create a "shadow" of the first input iterator.  If the second iterator terminates, you can fetch first iterator's value from the shadow iterator.

Here's one way to do it that uses existing tooling, that runs at C-speed, and that is memory efficient:

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> iterable1, iterable2 = 'abcde', 'xyz' 

>>> it1, shadow1 = tee(iterable1)
>>> it2 = iter(iterable2)
>>> combined = map(itemgetter(0, 1), zip(it1, it2, shadow1))
 
>>> list(combined)
[('a', 'x'), ('b', 'y'), ('c', 'z')]
>>> next(shadow1)
'd'
```

Comment: Awesome! Beats all other solutions in simplicity (and probably in speed since it is using libraries from Standard Library).

Comment: One additional question: why do you need to have `shadow1` in the `zip`?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. The *it1* iterator and the *shadow1* iterator are both in the *zip()* so that they will get consumed at the same rate.  That assumes that no more than one data element is kept in memory by the *teeobject*.

Answer (score 30):

One way would be to implement a generator that lets you cache the last value:

```
class cache_last(collections.abc.Iterator):
    """
    Wraps an iterable in an iterator that can retrieve the last value.

    .. attribute:: obj

       A reference to the wrapped iterable. Provided for convenience
       of one-line initializations.
    """
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.obj = iterable
        self._iter = iter(iterable)
        self._sentinel = object()

    @property
    def last(self):
        """
        The last object yielded by the wrapped iterator.

        Uninitialized iterators raise a `ValueError`. Exhausted
        iterators raise a `StopIteration`.
        """
        if self.exhausted:
            raise StopIteration
        return self._last

    @property
    def exhausted(self):
        """
        `True` if there are no more elements in the iterator.
        Violates EAFP, but convenient way to check if `last` is valid.
        Raise a `ValueError` if the iterator is not yet started.
        """
        if not hasattr(self, '_last'):
            raise ValueError('Not started!')
        return self._last is self._sentinel

    def __next__(self):
        """
        Retrieve, record, and return the next value of the iteration.
        """
        try:
            self._last = next(self._iter)
        except StopIteration:
            self._last = self._sentinel
            raise
        # An alternative that has fewer lines of code, but checks
        # for the return value one extra time, and loses the underlying
        # StopIteration:
        #self._last = next(self._iter, self._sentinel)
        #if self._last is self._sentinel:
        #    raise StopIteration
        return self._last

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        This object is already an iterator.
        """
        return self
```

To use this, wrap the inputs to `zip`:

```
gen1 = cache_last(range(10))
gen2 = iter(range(8))
list(zip(gen1, gen2))
print(gen1.last)
print(next(gen1))
```

It is important to make `gen2` an iterator rather than an iterable, so you can know which one was exhausted. If `gen2` is exhausted, you don't need to check `gen1.last`.

Another approach would be to override zip to accept a mutable sequence of iterables instead of separate iterables. That would allow you to replace iterables with a chained version that includes your "peeked" item:

```
def myzip(iterables):
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    while True:
        items = []
        for it in iterators:
            try:
                items.append(next(it))
            except StopIteration:
                for i, peeked in enumerate(items):
                    iterables[i] = itertools.chain([peeked], iterators[i])
                return
            else:
                yield tuple(items)

gens = [range(10), range(8)]
list(myzip(gens))
print(next(gens[0]))
```

This approach is problematic for many reasons. Not only will it lose the original iterable, but it will lose any of the useful properties the original object may have had by replacing it with a `chain` object.

Comment: @MadPhysicist. Love your answer with `cache_last`, and the fact that it does not alter the `next` behavior ... so bad it's not symetric (switching `gen1` and `gen2` in the zip will leads to different results).Cheers

Comment: @Jean-Francois. I've updated the iterator to respond properly to `last` calls after it's exhausted. That should help in figuring out if you need the last value or not. Also makes it more production-y.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I ran the code and the output of `print(gen1.last)
print(next(gen1)) ` is `None and 9`

Comment: @MadPhysicist  with some docstrings and all. Nice ;) I will check later when I have time. Thanks for the time spent

Comment: @Ch3steR. Thanks for the catch. I'd gotten too excited and deleted the return statement from `last`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist This new implementation seems didn't pass any the tests I have written here: https://repl.it/@jfthuong/MadPhysicistChester It raises the following error for most of the cases: `AttributeError: 'CacheLastNew' object has no attribute '_last'`

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. Sorry, I've been editing on mobile without a means to test the code. Fixed now. I was assigning to `prev` instead of `_last`.

Comment: There's no need to do all this work.  *itertools.tee()* is already designed to efficiently split an iterator stream and to remember unconsumed values.

Answer (score 18):

This is [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) implementation equivalent given in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
def zip(*iterables):
    # zip('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax By
    sentinel = object()
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    while iterators:
        result = []
        for it in iterators:
            elem = next(it, sentinel)
            if elem is sentinel:
                return
            result.append(elem)
        yield tuple(result)
```

In your  1st example `gen1 = my_gen(10)` and `gen2 = my_gen(8)`.
After both the generators are consumed until 7th iteration. Now in 8th iteration `gen1` calls `elem = next(it, sentinel)` which return 8 but when `gen2` calls `elem = next(it, sentinel)` it returns `sentinel`(because at this `gen2` is exhausted) and `if elem is sentinel` is satisfied and function executes return and stops. Now `next(gen1)` returns 9.

In your 2nd example `gen1 = gen(8)` and `gen2 = gen(10)`. After both the generators are consumed until 7th iteration. Now in 8th iteration `gen1` calls `elem = next(it, sentinel)` which returns `sentinel`(because at this point `gen1` is exhausted) and `if elem is sentinel` is satisfied and the function executes return and stops. Now `next(gen2)` returns 8.

Inspired by [Mad Physicist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61126744/68587), you could use this `Gen` wrapper to counter it:

**Edit**: To handle the cases pointed by [Jean-Francois T.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61126284/zipped-python-generators-with-2nd-one-being-shorter-how-to-retrieve-element-tha/61126511#comment108152275_61126511)

Once a value is consumed from the iterator it's gone forever from the the iterator and there's no in-place mutating method for iterators to add it back to the iterator. One work around is to store the last consumed value.

```
class Gen:
    def __init__(self,iterable):
        self.d = iter(iterable)
        self.sentinel = object()
        self.prev = self.sentinel
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    @property
    def last_val_consumed(self):
        if self.prev is None:
            raise StopIteration
        if self.prev == self.sentinel:
            raise ValueError('Nothing has been consumed')
        return self.prev
    def __next__(self):
        self.prev = next(self.d,None)
        if self.prev is None:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.prev
```

---

Examples:

```
# When `gen1` is larger than `gen2`
gen1 = Gen(range(10))
gen2 = Gen(range(8))
list(zip(gen1,gen2))
# [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7)]
gen1.last_val_consumed
# 8 #as it was the last values consumed
next(gen1)
# 9
gen1.last_val_consumed
# 9

# 2. When `gen1` or `gen2` is empty
gen1 = Gen(range(0))
gen2 = Gen(range(5))
list(zip(gen1,gen2))
gen1.last_val_consumed
# StopIteration error is raised
gen2.last_val_consumed
# ValueError is raised saying `ValueError: Nothing has been consumed`
```

Comment: Thank you @Ch3steR for the time spent on this problem. Your modification of MadPhysicist solution has several limitations:
#1. If `gen1 = cache_last(range(0))` and `gen2 = cache_last(range(2))` then after doing `list(zip(gen1, gen2)`, a call to `next(gen2)` will raise an `AttributeError: 'cache_last' object has no attribute 'prev'`.   #2. If gen1 is longer than gen2, after consuming all elements, `next(gen2)` will keep on returning the last value instead of `StopIteration`. I will mark MadPhysicist answer and THE answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. Yes agreed. You should mark his answer as the answer. This has limitations. I'll try to improve this answer to counter all cases. ;)

Comment: @Ch3steR I can help you shaking it if you want. I'm a professional in the field of Software Validation :)

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. I would love to. It would mean a lot. I'm a 3rd-year undergrad student.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. Edited the answer. So, it can handle the cases you mentioned. I would love to hear your feedback.

Comment: Good job, it passes all the tests I have written here: https://repl.it/@jfthuong/MadPhysicistChester  You can run them online, pretty convenient :)

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. Oh great ;) Not familiar with `pytest` but I understood the output.

Answer (score 10):

I can see you've found this answer already and it got brought up in the comments but I figured I'll make an answer out of it. You want to use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), which will replace the empty values of the shorter generator with `None`:

```
import itertools

def my_gen(n:int):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i

gen1 = my_gen(10)
gen2 = my_gen(8)

for i, j in itertools.zip_longest(gen1, gen2):
    print(i, j)
```

Prints:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 None
9 None
```

You can also supply a `fillvalue` argument when calling `zip_longest` to replace the `None` with a default value, but basically for your solution once you hit a `None` (either `i` or `j`) in the for loop, the other variable will have your `8`.

Comment: Thanks. I have indeed already came up with `zip_longest` and it was in my question actually. :)

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by @GrandPhuba's elucidation of `zip`, let's create a "safe" variant (unit-tested [here](https://repl.it/repls/DeficientProfitableTerabyte)):

```py
def safe_zip(*args):
    """
    Safe zip that restores last consumed element in eachgenerator
    if not able to consume an element in all of them

    Returns:
        * generators in tuple
        * generator for zipped generators
    """
  continue_ = True
  n = len(args)
  result = (_ for _ in [])
  while continue_:
    addend = []
    for i, gen in enumerate(args):
      try:
        value = next(gen)
        addend.append(value)
      except StopIteration:
        genlist = list(args)
        args = tuple([chain([v], g) for v, g in zip(addend, genlist[:i])]+genlist[i:])
        continue_ = False
        break
    if len(addend)==n: result = chain(result, [tuple(addend)])
  return args, result
```

Here is a basic test:

```
    g1, g2 = (i for i in range(10)), (i for i in range(4))
    # Create (g1, g2), g3 first, then loop over g3 as one would with zip
    (g1, g2), g3 = safe_zip(g1, g2)
    for a, b in g3:
        print(a, b)#(0, 0) to (3, 3)
    for x in g1:
        print(x)#4 to 9
```

Answer (score 5):

you could use [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice, tee

def zipped(gen1, gen2, pred=list):
    g11, g12 = tee(gen1)
    z = pred(zip(g11, gen2))

    return (islice(g12, len(z), None), gen2), z

gen1 = iter(range(10))
gen2 = iter(range(5))

(gen1, gen2), output = zipped(gen1, gen2)

print(output)
print(next(gen1))
# [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
# 5
```

Answer (score 2):

i don't think you can retrieve dropped value with basic for loop, because exhausted iterator, taken from `zip(..., ...).__iter__` being dropped once exhausted and you cant access it.

You should mutate your zip, then you can get position of dropped item with some hacky code)

```
z = zip(range(10), range(8))
for _ in iter(z.__next__, None):
    ...
_, (one, other) = z.__reduce__()
_, (i_one,), p_one = one.__reduce__() # p_one == current pos, 1 based
import itertools
val = next(itertools.islice(iter(i_one), p_one - 1, p_one))
```